# How would I know possible combinations of parameters an exe file ran via cmd can take?

Tags: windows, command-line, command-line-arguments

You can run some exe files from cmd.exe providing arguments.

example

```
P:\foo\boo “” user pass P:\system\ company foo –P boo
```

Is there any way to actually find out what parameters an exe can take?

Obviously I don't have access to the source code of a specific exe. All I am trying to find out is if it is possible without the owner's manual/docs to actually know what parameters can be passed. I am open to a solution involving reflection in C# etc

Any insights on this will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Your first port of call should be trying to run the exe from the command-prompt with `/?` which shows the help page for a given command/program e.g. `fc /?`

```
/A Displays only first and last lines for each set of differences.
/B Performs a binary comparison.
/C Disregards the case of letters.
...
```

Alternatively, you can enter `help executableName` which does the same thing.

This may also work for some third-party programs if they are designed for use with the command prompt, but they are not many.

Comment: can you please show an example for like Notepad? I can't get the right syntax for this

Comment: Notepad doesn't support a help page. `cmd` does, however. Try `help cmd` or `cmd /?` Windows is a little inconsistent with how help pages are displayed though, since `mstsc /?` produces it's help page in a separate window

Answer (score 0):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) has the functionality to do this.  Open your program normally and then launch process explorer.  Open its properties and take a look at the "Strings" tab.  Most of these strings won't mean anything, but the ones that do could well be command-line switches.  Test each of them in turn until you have a definitive list.  Unfortunately, if there is a simpler method - I don't know what it is!

Comment: For the example given, that won't find flag `P` as it's too short. The other arguments such as `P:\System\` appear to be parameters, which won't appear in the string table either.